# Yii routing problem

Tags: routes, yii

I've created controller QuizController and added action actionEasy().
But then I click to link like http://mysite/quiz/easy I've got 404 error.
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created your controller with gii or console, take a look at the `accessRules` method.

```
class MyController extends CController
{
    ......
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('deny',
                'actions'=>array('create', 'edit'),
                'users'=>array('?'),
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('delete'),
                'roles'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',
                'actions'=>array('delete'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

You may want to add the `easy` action to some allow array, depending on the permissions that it needs.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help. Maybe I need to describe routes in some file?

Comment: Can you post your controller code and describe folder structure?

Comment: <?php

class QuizController extends CController {

 public function actionEasy() {
  
 }
 
 public function actionMiddle() {
  
 }
 
 public function actionHard() {
  
 }
}

?> My controller. My directory structure is default.

Comment: Have you tried with http://mysite/index.php/quiz/easy ? If it works, you will have to put a `htaccess` file to make some rewrite rules.

Comment: Sorry, I've put my controller to /quiz/ dir, now I move it to the same level with SiteController, and when I click on a link, I've got a blank page.

Comment: Well that's ok then, you only have to render a view inside your action and you are done :D